# sharepoint 2013 accessing next list itemid

Tags: sharepoint

Hello Following is my code to access the next item id for list from content database

```
int listItemId = -1;
            try
            {
                SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
                Log("web object", TraceSeverity.High, EventSeverity.Error, "God damn it,it before web object creation");
                Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    Log("RunWithElevatedPrivileges", TraceSeverity.High, EventSeverity.Error, "God damn it,RunWithElevatedPrivileges");
                      using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(web.Site.ID))
                      {
                          Log("elevatedSite", TraceSeverity.High, EventSeverity.Error, "God damn it,elevatedSite");
                          if (elevatedSite.WebApplication.ContentDatabases.Count > 0)
                          {
                              Log("ContentDatabases.Count", TraceSeverity.High, EventSeverity.Error, "God damn it,eContentDatabases.Count");
                              //Get the connection string for the sharepoint database
                              string connString = elevatedSite.WebApplication.ContentDatabases[0].DatabaseConnectionString;
                              Log("connString", TraceSeverity.High, EventSeverity.Error, "God damn it,connString");
                              //Establish a connection
                              SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString);
                              Log("SqlConnection", TraceSeverity.High, EventSeverity.Error, "SqlConnection");
                              try
                              {
                                  con.Open();
                                  Log(" con.Open();", TraceSeverity.High, EventSeverity.Error, " con.Open();");
                                  //Query to get the next item id for a list(Filtering the list by the list id)
                                  SqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand();
                                  Log(" SqlCommand ", TraceSeverity.High, EventSeverity.Error, " SqlCommand ");
                                  //This command is changed by yogesh for sharepoint 2010 to get next avalable ID in a list
                                  //com.CommandText = String.Format("select tp_NextAvailableId from AllLists where tp_ID = '{0}'", listId.ToString());
                                  com.CommandText = String.Format("select NextAvailableId from AllListsAux where ListID = '{0}'", listId.ToString());
                                  Log("com.CommandText ", TraceSeverity.High, EventSeverity.Error, "com.CommandText ");
                                  listItemId = (int)com.ExecuteScalar();
                                  Log("listItemId", TraceSeverity.High, EventSeverity.Error, "listItemId");
                              }
                              finally
                              {
                                  con.Close();
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  });

            }
```

This code is working fine but when I deployed my code in PPD its giving me error of the

Below is the stack trace error I am not able to understand the problem please help me out soon

*God damn it,it before web object creation 304d2c9d-7d0d-207c-3e44-95108fc65117
09/09/2015 17:07:58.25 w3wp.exe (0x2EC0)                       0x4250  Unknown                       RunWithElevatedPrivileges

00000 High

God damn it,RunWithElevatedPrivileges  304d2c9d-7d0d-207c-3e44-95108fc65117
09/09/2015 17:07:58.25 w3wp.exe (0x2EC0)                       0x4250  SharePoint Foundation         Database

ahjqp High

[Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 09/09/2015 17:07:58.24, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.0291936545007815 for Data Source=MOC-MHX-SQLC06\PPD_BIZAPP2013;Initial Catalog=WSS_Content_PERApplication_new;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application Name=SharePoint[w3wp][2][WSS_Content_PERApplication_new]
304d2c9d-7d0d-207c-3e44-95108fc65117
09/09/2015 17:07:58.25 w3wp.exe (0x2EC0)                       0x4250  SharePoint Foundation         General                       6t8j High

[Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] {0}
304d2c9d-7d0d-207c-3e44-95108fc65117
09/09/2015 17:07:58.25 w3wp.exe (0x2EC0)                       0x4250  Unknown                       elevatedSite

00000 High

God damn it,elevatedSite 304d2c9d-7d0d-207c-3e44-95108fc65117
09/09/2015 17:07:58.25 w3wp.exe (0x2EC0)                       0x4250  Unknown                       ContentDatabases.Count

00000 High

God damn it,eContentDatabases.Count 304d2c9d-7d0d-207c-3e44-95108fc65117
09/09/2015 17:07:58.25 w3wp.exe (0x2EC0)                       0x4250  Unknown                       connString

00000 High

God damn it,connString 304d2c9d-7d0d-207c-3e44-95108fc65117
09/09/2015 17:07:58.25 w3wp.exe (0x2EC0)                       0x4250  Unknown                       SqlConnection                 00000 High

SqlConnection 304d2c9d-7d0d-207c-3e44-95108fc65117
09/09/2015 17:07:58.27 w3wp.exe (0x2EC0)                       0x4250  Unknown                       con.Open();

00000 High

con.Open(); 304d2c9d-7d0d-207c-3e44-95108fc65117
09/09/2015 17:07:58.27 w3wp.exe (0x2EC0)                       0x4250  Unknown                       SqlCommand                   00000 High

SqlCommand 304d2c9d-7d0d-207c-3e44-95108fc65117
09/09/2015 17:07:58.27 w3wp.exe (0x2EC0)                       0x4250  Unknown                       com.CommandText               00000 High

com.CommandText 304d2c9d-7d0d-207c-3e44-95108fc65117
09/09/2015 17:07:58.33 w3wp.exe (0x2EC0)                       0x4250  SharePoint Foundation         Database

ahjqp High

[Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 09/09/2015 17:07:58.28, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.0308000039111116 for Data Source=MOC-MHX-SQLC06\PPD_BIZAPP2013;Initial Catalog=WSS_Content_PERApplication_new;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application Name=SharePoint[w3wp][2][WSS_Content_PERApplication_new]
304d2c9d-7d0d-207c-3e44-95108fc65117
09/09/2015 17:07:58.33 w3wp.exe (0x2EC0)                       0x4250  SharePoint Foundation         General                       ama7l High

[Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] SPListItem.AddOrUpdateItem: begin
304d2c9d-7d0d-207c-3e44-95108fc65117
09/09/2015 17:07:58.41 w3wp.exe (0x2EC0)                       0x4250  SharePoint Foundation         Dev Events

ahk8b High

[Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] Calling ExecuteItemEventReceivers() for list {0} on item {1}
304d2c9d-7d0d-207c-3e44-95108fc65117
09/09/2015 17:07:58.50 w3wp.exe (0x2EC0)                       0x4250  SharePoint Foundation         Dev Events

ajekb High

[Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 09/09/2015 17:07:58.43, Original Level: Verbose] Invoking EventReceiver - [Id: {0}]
304d2c9d-7d0d-207c-3e44-95108fc65117
09/09/2015 17:07:58.50 w3wp.exe (0x2EC0)                       0x4250  SharePoint Foundation         Database

8acb High

[Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: VerboseEx] Reverting to process identity
304d2c9d-7d0d-207c-3e44-95108fc65117
09/09/2015 17:07:58.53 w3wp.exe (0x2EC0)                       0x47B4  SharePoint Foundation         Dev Events

ajbpn Medium

Set EventFiringDisabled to [False].  Stack trace: [   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventManager.HandleEventCallback[ReceiverType,PropertiesType](Object callbackData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPThreadPool.WaitCallbackWrapper(Object state)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()     at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()  ]
264d2c9d-1dd5-207c-3e44-9aa480fb3752
09/09/2015 17:07:58.57 w3wp.exe (0x2EC0)                       0x4250  SharePoint Foundation         Topology

ebe8 Medium

init for Farm account Sid 304d2c9d-7d0d-207c-3e44-95108fc65117*

Comment: you need to format your question.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you getting this value from the database? Rule of thumb in SharePoint - stay away from the database.

I don't know what's your exact scenario, but maybe you could get that value directly from the list using query?

I don't have example query at hand, but you could limit the amount of results to one, order the result by ID field in descending order, read the value and voila!